# Why is the scanf() skipped?

Tags: c, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char opt;
    scanf(" %c", &opt);
    switch (opt) {
      case 'A':
        printf("Please Enter a New Name:");
        char name[200];
        scanf("%[^\n]s", name);

        printf("Please Enter a New Code:");
        char code[200];
        scanf("%s", code);

        printf("Please Enter the Number:");
        int number;
        scanf("%d", number);

        printf("%s\n%s\n%d", name, code, number);
        printf("\nPlease press Enter to confirm Creation");
    }
}
```

Why is the `scanf` of the name skipped? the output looks like

```
A
Please Enter a New Name:Please Enter a New Code:
```

Also when `switch()` is removed, it works normally. Is the problem on the `switch()`? It does not have other cases because it is an unfinished code.

Comment: Your first `scanf` leaves a `\n` on the buffer. Second one sees it and stops reading, also leaving it in the buffer, so does the third one. When it finally comes to the forth one, `%d` format string ignores it and waits for you. Don't use `scanf` to get input from user, [see](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html).

Comment: @melonduofromage Please create an answer.

Comment: I also don't believe for a minute the claim "when switch() is removed, it works normally", unless "normally" means it fails as-designed. That isn't the only change if this magically starts working. The trailing `s` on that name read assuredly wrong, and `scanf("%d", number);` is absolutely wrong. There is no way this runs well.

Comment: @WhozCraig: removing both the `switch` and the `scanf(" %c", &opt);` does change the behavior.

Comment: And so the `scanf("%[^\n]s", name);` should be `scanf(" %199[^\n]", name);` (three changes a) space to filter newline, b) length restriction, c) remove the "beginner's `s`"). Please see [scanf() leaves the newline char in the buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/scanf-leaves-the-new-line-char-in-the-buffer).

Comment: @chqrlie Sure, but the OP never claimed they removed the `scanf(" %c", &opt);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented by *melonduofromage*, your first scanf leaves the newline (`\n`) typed by the user after the `A` in the input stream. Next `scanf("%[^\n]s", name)` fails because the first byte from the input stream is a newline, so `scanf` returns immediately with a return value of `0`, which you should not ignore. The program then prompts for the code and `scanf` skips initial white space, including the pending newline and waits for user input.

To fix this problem, add a space before the conversion specifier to skip initial white space.  You should also limit the number of characters stored into the destination array: specify this number between the `%` and the `[`. Note also that the trailing `s` in `"%[^\n]s"` is useless: it is not part of the conversion specifier and `scanf()` will try and match it against the input stream. The correct format is `scanf(" %199[^\n]", name)` and the return value must be `1` for a successful conversion.

Also note that there is a missing `&` in `scanf("%d", number)`: you must pass the address of the destination variable: `scanf("%d", &number);`

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int invalid_input(void) {
    fprintf(stderr, "invalid or missing input\n");
    return 1;
} 

int main() {
    char opt;
    if (scanf(" %c", &opt) != 1)
        return invalid_input();

    switch (opt) {
      case 'A':
        printf("Please Enter a New Name:");
        char name[200];
        if (scanf(" %199[^\n]", name) != 1)
            return invalid_input();

        printf("Please Enter a New Code:");
        char code[200];
        if (scanf("%199s", code) != 1)
            return invalid_input();

        printf("Please Enter the Number:");
        int number;
        if (scanf("%d", &number) != 1)
            return invalid_input();

        printf("%s\n%s\n%d", name, code, number);
        printf("\nPlease press Enter to confirm Creation");
        //...
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you prompt user with the first `scanf` here

```
char opt;
scanf(" %c", &opt);
```

When the user enters a character, say `A`, "A\n" is placed in the buffer, `\n` coming from the user hitting the return key. The `scanf` takes one character as requested with the `" %c"` format string, and leaves the `\n` on the buffer.

When the second `scanf` is executed as

```
printf("Please Enter a New Name:");
char name[200];
scanf("%[^\n]s", name);
```

the format string `"%[^\n]s"` requests it to read until a `\n` is encountered, mind you, your buffer already contains a `\n` as the first character, hence `scanf` returns without reading anything, still leaving the `\n` in the buffer.

When the third `scanf` is executed as:

```
printf("Please Enter a New Code:");
char code[200];
scanf("%s", code);
```

*(Corrected after the comments of chqrlie)*

The format string `"%s"` ignores the leading whitespaces, hence now the `\n` is ignored, and `scanf` happily waits for your input.

Notice the leading space in the format string `" %c"`, the space is there to get `scanf` ignore the leading whitespace, you can implement the same logic with your second `scanf`. You can either ensure that all consecutive `scanf` ignore the `\n` left in the buffer, which turns out most format specifiers do, or you can ensure that no `scanf` leaves it to begin with with using something like `"<...>%*c"` to get rid of it. Though none of which are reliable and consistent methods, and as said countless times, `scanf` is not designed to perform such tasks like taking user input, and you should seek alternative methods.

Also, the `s` in `"%[^\n]s"` certainly doesn't do what you expect. man page of the `scanf` states that

> An  ordinary  character  (i.e., one other than white space or '%').  This character must exactly match the next character of input.

If it matches, `scanf` discards it and continues parsing according to the remaining format specifiers. If it doesn't, `scanf` stops there and returns. Since it is at the end of your format string, it returns either way, hiding a potential bug from you.

Comment: Also the `s` in `"%[^\n]s"` is more than just redundant, `scanf()` will try to match the next byte against an `s`, which must fail as the next byte is a newline unless the end of file has been reached.

Comment: The `scanf` conversion stops at the first character it cannot convert, which is typically (but not necessarily) a space or a newline, and that character remains in the input buffer. It will be read by the *next* `scanf()`. Most format specifiers automatically filter leading whitespace characters from the input, but `%c` and `%[]` and `%n` do not. You can instruct `scanf` to do so by adding a space just before the `%`. Whitespace in the format string is meaningful: sometimes redundant, but *trailing* whitespace can be harmful.

Comment: @chqrlie Will it though? Wouldn't it be `"%[^\n]%s"` for that to be the case?

Comment: Oh right, it will try to match it against the character `s` not a string,

Comment: @melonduofromage: characters in the `scanf()` format string that are not part of a conversion specification, nor whitespace, are matched against the stream contents. No undefined behavior because of the trailing `s`, but if one does not specify `%199[^\n]`, a line longer than 199 bytes will cause undefined behavior as `scanf()` will store bytes beyond the end of the 200 byte destination array.

Comment: @WeatherVane Which is guaranteed to result in an another question as soon as OP tries to use something like `fgets` after the `scanf`s

Comment: `scanf()` is full of traps and pitfalls. It takes implementing it and passing a validation suite to fully understand its intricacies. This function is painfully inadequate for beginners to read user contents. A systematic combination of `fgets()` and `sscanf()` is a more sensible approach, with an opportunity for error handling and recovery.

Comment: @melonduofromage I did not suggest they should. An understanding of how the input functions handle incoming whitespace, and the significance of whitespace in the `scanf` format string, is crucial to mastering user input. The functions all work differently, and the format specifiers also work differently.